# How to change Save Location of CPH Judge Extension in VScode?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I want to save my .bin file in cph folder in my workspace, but I can only set the location as `/Users/User-Name/Path-to-My_workspace/cph`, and if I set `${workspaceFolder}/cph` which appear error and cannot work successfully.

I also tried `${workspaceFolderBasename}` or `${fileWorkspaceFolder}`, but they always show 'Invaild save location'.